# Functional equation 2.0

Tags: functional-equations

Find all continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$
such that :
$$f(\sqrt 2 \, x)=2f(x)$$
$$f(x+1)=f(x)+2x+1$$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Clearly $x^2$ is a valid solution but how can i find other solutions or prove that there is no other solution?
And please give me ressources for studying functional equations and some advanced techniques cause the techniques I use are still for a beginner level

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150733/discussion-on-question-by-mohamed-raed-functional-equation-2-0); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

We note that $x\mapsto x^2$ is a possible solution for $f(x)$.

Working on the theory that this is the only possible solution, we define $$G(x)=f(x)-x^2$$ and note that $$G(\sqrt 2\,x)=2G(x)\quad \&\quad G(x+1)=G(x)$$

We'd like to show that $G(x)$ was identically $0$.

Now, $G(x)$ is continuous and periodic.  That means that it attains a global maximum, $M$. Let $G(x_0)=M$. We remark that $M≥0$ since $G(0)=0$.  But then $$G(\sqrt 2\,x_0)=2M\implies 2M≤M\implies  M=0$$ A similar argument shows that the global minimum is also $0$ and we are done.

Comment: I have already read your last comment, but could you tell me if in your opinion it is possible to prove that $G(x)=0$ for any $x\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ and, in the case that it is possible, how can we do it? Moreover, what do you think about my answer? Is there  an easier way to prove that $G(x)=0$ for any $x\in\Bbb Q\,?\;$

Comment: @Angelo  Yes...my guess (which might well be wrong) is that all of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is in one equivalence class.  Maybe it is a whole equivalence class. Anyway, that's what I suggest proving (or disproving).  As you noticed, my argument that there were infinitely many equivalence classes was purely set theoretic...I certianly didn't show how to produce them.

Comment: @Angelo  But first, it's necessary to prove that my vague sketch makes sense.  Maybe it doesn't.  It's not that easy to "meld" two equivalence classes...suppose $x\sim y$ because they differ by an integer and $y\sim z$ because their ratio is a power of $\sqrt 2$.  Is it true that $x\sim z$?  Maybe not.  If that fails, then my counterexample doesn't work.

Comment: Lulu, please could you try to prove that $G(x)=0$ for any $x\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\,?\;$ I have tried but I have not managed to get it.

Comment: I'm focussed on something else at the moment, but I'll come back to this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,G\,$ be the function defined as $\,G(x)=f(x)-x^2$ for all $\,x\in\Bbb R\,.\,$ Without using continuity, we can prove that $\,G(r)=0\,$ for any $\,r\in\Bbb Q\,.$

Let $\,\varphi\,$ be the [Euler’s totient function](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/t/t212.htm).

For any $\,r\in\Bbb Q\,$ there exist $\,a,d\in\Bbb Z\,,\,$ $b,c\in\Bbb N_0=\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\,$ such that

$r\!=\!\dfrac a{2^b(2c\!+\!1)}\;\;,\qquad$ $2^{\varphi(2c+1)}\!=\!1\!+\!(2c\!+\!1)d\;.$

Since $\,G(2^nx)\!=\!4^nG(x)\,$ and $\,G(x\!+\!m)\!=\!G(x)\,$ for any $\,n,m\in\Bbb Z\,$ and for any $\,x\in\Bbb R\,,\,$ it follows that$$4^{\phi(2c+1)+b}G(r)=G\!\left(2^{\phi(2c+1)+b}r\right)=G\left(2^br[1\!+\!(2c\!+\!1)d]\right)=G\left(2^br\!+\!ad\right)=G\left(2^br\right)=4^bG(r)$$Consequently , $\;G(r)=0\,.$

It means that $\,f(x)=x^2\,$ for any $\,x\in\Bbb Q\,$ even if the function $\,f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\,$ is not continuous.